# 'library is corrupt' error in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, linker, visual-studio-2017, wininet

I am trying to use Windows Driver Kit and Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 in my VS 2017 code.

It is giving me linking error, 'library is corrupt' for the file 'wininet.lib'. I tried reinstalling both SDKs and still error is there.

How can I solve this issue? I can use SDKs version 10.0.22000.0 in VS 2019 only?

Please help

Comment: Did this ever work on your machine or is this the first time you are trying to build?  What version of VS are you using?  You mentioned both 2017 and 2019.  can you show the code of where you are using/linking this dll?

Comment: @eglease I am working in 2017. I am using the latest SDK (10.0.22000.0) for this. 10.0.22000.0 is not a part of 2017. My question I can use Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 with VS 2019 only?

In VS 2017 I am getting error like,  'library is corrupt' for the file 'wininet.lib'.

Comment: I can't find anywhere where it says that VS2017 does not support the latest SDK but the SDK page itself only mentions VS2019.  10.0.17763.0 was the last version included with VS2017 so I suspect it no longer supports it.

Comment: VS 2017 (15.9) works up through Windows SDK (19041) without any issues. BTW, VS 2017 reached the end of mainstream support on April 2022.